# Node Jest mocking a function in a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocking, jestjs

I am Testing a method like such:

```
test('Test', async () => {
    const result = await methodBeingTested(someData);
    })
})
```

Then the method I am testing looks something like this:

```
import { insertData } from '../util/api';
export async function methodBeingTested(someData: any) {
    const data = await insertData(dateIdsomeData)

    //Do Some other stuff
    return data
}
```

I would like to mock the data `insertData` method returns just so it doesn't do the axios request or the insert into mongo / sql.

How am I able to do this with Jest? I am mainly just wanting to test the functionality of the other stuff going on in the `methodBeingTested`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
jest.mock('../util/api', () => ({
   insertData: () => Promise.resolve(mockResult) // put here some result 
}));

// your tests
```

Just make sure that your path is correct.